# Obtaining latitude and longitude on Earth from Satellite location and pointing angles

Tags: python, coordinates, latitude-longitude, satellite

Considering the Earth as a perfect sphere and knowing the position (latitude,longitude and height) of a satellite.

I would like to transform the pointing angle from the satellite (defined by two angles) to latitude and longitude over the Earth surface.

I could try to compute intersections of lines and spheres to get it, but I think there are some packages in Python such as Pyproj that compute coordinate transformations (faster and more accurate), but I haven't managed to get something as I request.

Comment: What's the "pointing angle from the satellite"? Do you mean something like the azimuth and altitude angles from a point on the earth to the satellite? The direction you need to point an antenna to be looking at the satellite from a given earth-bound lat-long?

Comment: The pointing angle is from the satellite. I generally used theta(elevation), phi(azimuth). Being (theta,phi)=(0,0) is pointing towards the center of the Earth. Considering a GEO orbit, (theta,phi)=(9º,0) will be pointing to the end of Earth approximately and with phi it varies this "end of Earth" counter clockwise